# rewriting hypothesis to false with a contradictory theorem

Tags: coq, ssreflect

I want to show that

```
[seq q x t | x <- iota 0 (t + 1)] != [::]
```

I decided to destruct `iota 0 (t + 1)` because I have a lemma that says:

```
iota 0 (t + 1) != [::]
```

So the first case of destruct should have `iota 0 (t + 1) = [::]` which by the theorem mentioned is false, and I can discriminate. How can I rewrite the equation in the first destruct case using the lemma? I cannot figure it out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to destruct. Note that `iota` is defined by recursion on its second variable. Your current goal cannot be simplified because `t + 1` does not start with a constructor.  However, you can do `by rewrite addn1` to put it in a form where it can be solved.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to computation, as Arthur suggests, you can sometimes use contraposition to deal with non-equalities (do `Search "contra"` for variant versions).

For instance, in your case, you can show, if you add some injectivity constraint:

```
Lemma foo (q : nat -> nat -> nat) t (injq: injective (q^~ t)) :
  iota 0 (t + 1) != [::] -> [seq q x t | x <- iota 0 (t + 1)] != [::].
Proof.
apply: contra_neq.
rewrite [RHS]( _ : [::] = [seq q x t | x <- [::]]) //.
exact: inj_map. 
Qed.
```